# Page Webhooks + Messenger Event

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

Rookie facebook api/developer user here. I have a couple questions hoping someone can shed some light on.

My use-case:

- Facebook page user leaves rating/review
- App receives webhook event with information about webhook event
  (https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/webhooks/reference/page)
- Using that event info, we initiate a messenger chat conversation with
  the user

This seems like a common scenario.

My understanding of what needs to be done:

- Create a facebook app
- Add page webhooks product to app (specifically subscribe to ratings
  event)
- Wire up webhooks to my API (exposed via ngrok)
- Add messenger product to app
- ...Somehow initiate convo with user (using reviewer_id??)

Does anyone have a good description of how to do this from end-to-end?
I have done most of this, but I cannot figure out how to do this in the test/sandbox facebook. Do I need to create a test version of my app, create a test page, and then use the graph api to subscribe the test app to the test page?

Thanks guys. The docs are nice and all, but there's no detailed directions on testing this end-to-end on the sandbox facebook. I don't have time to wait for an app review to test the functionality.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: How do you initiate a messenger chat conversation?

Comment: @WizKid I do not know. I haven't gotten that far. Seems there should be a way to converse with a user if they have left a review on your business page.

Comment: I would suggest you verify that before you start building stuff.

Comment: @WizKid yes, thanks. Ignoring that aspect for now.. my page webhooks do not even fire. my callback url verification works fine. Subscribed my app to a page, I never see any webhook events when I test it... thoughts?

Comment: I don’t think you should ignore it for now - dealing with the fact/realization, that you _can not_ initiate a conversation with the user from your end, only much later on into this project, might be a bit frustrating …

Comment: It is called a "Private Reply" where the user makes a post/comment on a page and we can initiate a conversation with them.